# SQL Query: Move data from one database to another

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I want to move data from a table in `database1` to a table in `database2` in Oracle SQL developer.

This is the query that I am writing: -

```
INSERT INTO <DESTINATION_DB>.<TABLE_NAME> (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES (
 SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM <SOURCE_DB>.<TABLE_NAME> WHERE <CONDITION>
);
```

When I try to run this query, I am getting this error: -

> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Can someone help?

Comment: how is this related to java?

Comment: Yes not related to Java, and your query looks ok by structure maybe you can post original query so someone can help to find the real issue.

Comment: You need to post the original query

Comment: When you use the term "database" you mean *database*? Or do you actually mean *schema* (i.e. different user in the same physical database)? Oracle terminology differs from other RDBMS products you may have used previously, and it's a good idea to get the concepts straight in your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a query as the source of an insert, don't use the `values` clause:

```
INSERT INTO target_schema.table_name (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) 
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 
FROM source_schema.table_name 
WHERE <CONDITION>;
```

Note that the prefix of a table is not "a database", it's a schema name

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can recollect from one of the conversation asked in `asktom.oracle.com` is that 
create database link and simply execute

```
insert into local_table select * from table@database_link;
```

Comment: It's good that you know about AskTom but looking at the OP's pseudo-code it seems more likely that they have confused the terms "schema" with "database" as used in other RDBMS products such as MySQL.